# Dynamo db pagination node.js

Tags: node.js, pagination, amazon-dynamodb

I use node.js and @aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb.
I want to get all items from dynamo table with pagination but I receive only ~327 items by every request for instance 400 or more items. dynamodb has 750 items.

```
async getAllArtObjectIds(pageSize = 400, startKey) {
    const scanParams = {
        TableName: this.tableName,
        Limit: pageSize,
        ExclusiveStartKey: startKey,
    };

    const scanResults = [];
    let items;
    let itemsCount = 0;

    do {
        items = await this.docClient.send(new ScanCommand(scanParams));
        items.Items.forEach((item) => {
            scanResults.push({
                artObjectId: item.artObjectId,
                partitionKey: item.PartitionKey,
                isApproved: item.isApproved,
            });
        });

        console.log('item', items.Items.length);
        itemsCount += items.Items.length;
        scanParams.ExclusiveStartKey = items.LastEvaluatedKey;
    } while (items.LastEvaluatedKey);

    console.log('scan.len', scanResults.length);
    return {
        data: scanResults,
        lastEvaluatedKey: items.LastEvaluatedKey,
    };
}
```

what's wrong? why I don't get all needed items?

Comment: What's the calling code?

Comment: async getListOfArtObjectIds(pageSize = 400, startKey?): Promise<any[]> {
    try {
      const { data } = await this.getAllArtObjectIds(pageSize, startKey);
      const res = data.map((item) => ({
        artObjectId: item.artObjectId,
        partitionKey: item.partitionKey,
        isApproved: item.isApproved,
      }));
      return res;
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Error getting list of ArtObject IDs:', err);
      throw err;
    }
  }

Comment: async getListOfArtObject(
    pageSize: number,
    startKey?: any,
  ): Promise<{ data: any[]; totalQuantity: number }> {
    try {
      const data = await this.dynamoPhotoObjectRepository.getListOfArtObjectIds(
        pageSize,
        startKey,
      );
      const totalQuantity =
        await this.dynamoPhotoObjectRepository.getTotalItemCount();
      return {
        data: data,
        totalQuantity,
      };
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Error getting list of ArtObjects:', err);
      throw err;
    }
  }

Comment: @Query(() => ResponseObjectType)
  async getListOfArtObject(
    @Args('PageSize', { nullable: true }) pageSize?: number,
    @Args('startKey', { nullable: true }) startKey?: string,
  ): Promise<ResponseObjectType> {
    const data = await this.dynamoPhotoObjectsService.getListOfArtObject(
      pageSize || 1,
      { PartitionKey: startKey || '0' },
    );
    return {
      data: data.data,
      totalQuantity: data.totalQuantity,
    };
  }

Comment: What are you passing in as startKey when calling the code?

Comment: {
  getListOfArtObject(PageSize: 400) {
    data {
     partitionKey
      artObjectId
      isApproved
    }
    totalQuantity
  }
}

Comment: async paginateScan(pageSize: number, startKey) {
    const params: ScanCommandInput = {
      TableName: this.tableName,
      Limit: pageSize,
      ExclusiveStartKey: {
        PartitionKey: '37-30203-20231105161842',
      },
    };
    const paginator = paginateScan({ client: this.docClient }, params);
    const queryResults = [];
    let lastEvaluatedKey = null;
    for await (const page of paginator) {
      queryResults.push(...page.Items);
      lastEvaluatedKey = page.LastEvaluatedKey;
      if (queryResults.length >= pageSize) {
        break;
      }
    }
  }

Comment: I have another variant but in this case function always starts with firs item even I define first element

Comment: How do you know it's the first item?

Comment: I do request for 10 items. Then take for example third item from this list and define it partition key in next request but I get the same list from first item

Comment: Why are you doing it like that, what's your use case? Why not use the LastEvaluatedKey as intended?

Comment: for example my front asks me to get 400 items, but back-end can return only ~327items in this function items = await this.docClient.send(new ScanCommand(scanParams)); (method getAllArtObjectIds)

Comment: Leeroy, please tell me what better to use paginateScan or ScanCommand from @aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb?

Comment: Yes in that case you get 327 and you submit the LastEvaluatedKey you got returned as the ExclusiveStartKey and you set the limit to 33.

Comment: I prefer the ScanCommand over the autopaginator.

Comment: I define ExclusiveStartKey as LastEvaluatedKey and do while (items.LastEvaluatedKey). I get such part of (items.Items.length) - item.length 75
item.length 73
item.length 77
item.length 80
item.length 49
scan.len 354. I cannot receive all 400 items

Answer (score 0):

This example below works as expected. I loaded 400 large items into a table. DynamoDB has a 1MB page size limit, so I was able to fit 17 items per page.

```
const { DynamoDBClient } = require("@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb");
const { DynamoDBDocumentClient, ScanCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb");
const client = new DynamoDBClient({});
const docClient = DynamoDBDocumentClient.from(client);

const get = async () => {

    const startKey = null;
    const scanResults = [];
    let items;
    let itemsCount = 0;

    const scanParams = {
        TableName: 'test',
        Limit: 400,
        ExclusiveStartKey: startKey,
    };

    do {
        items = await docClient.send(new ScanCommand(scanParams));
        items.Items.forEach((item) => {
            scanResults.push(item);
        });

        console.log('item', items.Items.length);
        itemsCount += items.Items.length;
        scanParams.ExclusiveStartKey = items.LastEvaluatedKey;
    } while (items.LastEvaluatedKey);

    console.log('scan.len', scanResults.length);
    return {
        data: scanResults,
        lastEvaluatedKey: items.LastEvaluatedKey,
    };

}

get();
```

Results:

- 23 pages of 17 items;
- 1 page of 9 items;
- **scan.len 400**

Comment: do you have some examples of such situation? maybe GitHub...

Comment: I see in dynamo settings that I can choose pagesize max 300 items for page. Might it related to my issue? I get 329 for request of 400, 500 etc?

Comment: Ive updated a working example.

Comment: Leeroy, thank you!!! I've done it. I have code similar your example, but I have to slice  scanResults.slice(0, pageSize) because limit doesn't work.